# Datatables and slow Ajax sourced data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatable

I'm using datatable script to fill a table of large number of rows...

Call to datatable and jquery was like this

```
<table id="table" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
 <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>column 1</th>
    <th>column 2</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
</table>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": 'script.php'
    } );
} );
```

And this is a sample of SCRIPT.PHP to read data from a mysql database

```
$data = array();

$sql = "SELECT a, b FROM database";
$res = $db->query($sql);
while ($f = $res->fetch()) {
  $nestedData=array(); 
  $nestedData[] = $f['a'];
  $nestedData[] = $f['b'];
  $data[] = $nestedData;
}
$json_data = array( "data" => $data );
echo json_encode($json_data);
```

The PROBLEM was that in this way I must attend loading of data from database (on large db, the wait was very long) and then the tables was filled, but I want to fill data for each row read from database...

How is this possibile?

Answer (score 2):

I can only think about 3 ways:

1. Create a pager for your table in order to fetch/show 10 or 20 rows at a time
2. Make a tree and categorize you data (example : http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=wiki:treegrid.png)
3. If your data are not frequently modified, you can create a cache. (save you generated json in a file and refresh it each 10minutes/hours)

Answer (score 2):

## Solution 1 : LIMIT NUMBER OF RESULTS

You can limit results to print only the newest or active like :

```
$sql = "SELECT a, b FROM database ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,50 ";
```

or create a column 'Created_Date' to get only for the last week :

```
$sql = "SELECT a, b FROM database WHERE Created_Date >= DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE())";

$json_data = array( "data" => $db->query($sql)->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ));
echo json_encode($json_data);
```

## Solution 2 : using a search solution

a search solution provide : distributed indexing, replication and load-balanced querying

like :

- Lucene/Solr
- ElasticSearch
- groonga
- Sphinx
- ...